# extracting URL from tag

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm looking to parse through an HTML request that contains the element:

```
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/...." alt="Embedded image permalink"</a>
```

To try to get the img src tag. All I want is the URL.

At this point I'm probably going overboard.  Using Request and Cheerio to try to accomplish this.

Of the 20 different ways that I've tried to do this here's my current code.

```
var dummy;
request('http://t.co/....', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
    dummy = $('img[alt=Embedded image permalink]').attr('html');
    console.dir(dummy);
  }
}
```

I get the error message:

```
selector = selector.substr(data[0].length);
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

As I've said, probably overcomplicating this.  What's the simplest (or just functional) way to do this?

Comment: Why won't you just use something more trivial, like string functions and regex?

Comment: I'm definitely over complicating things.  Started with regex, but my regex skills weren't up to snuff - abandoned it and went this direction instead.  Jeremy, tried that and just got undefined error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regexp!

Something like this should do the trick:

```
html.match(/<img [^>]*src="([^"]*)"/g)
```

See working example here: http://www.rubular.com/r/f89Y9fHGtN (Caution: Ruby regexes are a bit different than JS ones, but I don't know such a cool tool for the latter.)

---

Regexp explained:

`<img` – this matches beginning of the tag.

`[^>]*` – a bit tricky. This gets rid of things in front of `src` argument (`alt` argument, for example). This version fails when there's a `>` char inside of an argument, which probably should not happen. You may try replacing this part with `.*`, which will work in that case, failing on the other hand when an argument value ends with `src=`.

`src="` – this finds the src argument.

`([^"]*)` – **captures** the URL inside.

`"` – finds end of the value.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Closer with both approaches! so here's what's up now.  Take this URL for example:  https://twitter.com/LindsayBaines/status/355971561175531520/photo/1/large  and run the HTML through rubular.  You get all the images on the page.  I'm trying to whittle it down to the one with :large appended to the end. That's why I was trying to get match this...
 data-url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BPCqP7ZCQAEe1Pg.png:large" 
 data-resolved-url-large="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BPCqP7ZCQAEe1Pg.png:large">

Comment: Does this help? `html.match(/<img [^>]*src="([^"]*:large)"/g)`

Comment: Just to be clear, I've only added `:large` part to the capturing block.

Comment: arghhh... I should have figured that out :)  I was playing with the beginning of the expression.  not the end.  I have one last challenge I'm working on with it.  I get back <img class="large media-slideshow-image" alt="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BPCqP7ZCQAEe1Pg.png:large"  so to get the URL inside of the ""'s alone.  Workin on it. Thank you so much for the help Hubert.  Feel like I'm playing with Perl circa 1997.

Comment: Ha: body.match(/https:([^"]*:large)/g); works ---- except it will also match a string where trailing characters after :large exist.

Comment: You can do it in two steps, mine regex on the body, yours on the result - then you won't have this problem. Too bad that `match` in JS doesn't return array of arrays.

Comment: Also, if there's just one occurrence on the page, like in this case, you can skip `g` in regex options, so you'll have `html.match(/<img [^>]*src="([^"]*:large)"/)`. In this case, the capture group is included in the returned array.

Comment: Or, take your regex and add a lookahead: `body.match(/https:([^"]*:large)(?=")/);`.

Comment: A strongly recommended lecture if you want to finally understand what's going on in regexes: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596520694.do :)

Comment: I'm going to have to do that - thanks again, I got it with the lookahead - after keeping the /g actually :)  Have a good one, appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want to substract the `url` immediatly following the `src` string in a string of text?

Why don't you put all the text in a variable and then double split it?

For example:

```
    var arrayOfElements = $("#txt").val().split("src=");
    var replacing = arrayOfElements[1].replace(/"/g, "'");
    var url = replacing.split("'");

    //You can now access the element by using url[1]
```

You can see a working example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fVfPG/). Good luck!